# R installation on Ubuntu, how to fix this error message?

Tags: r, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-20.04

I'm quite new to Unix systems and I just can't understand why I'm having this problem during the installation of R on Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa.

I have installed R using the following procedure:

- checked for the presence of the string deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ in my /etc/apt/sources.list file;
- used commands: **sudo apt-get update** and then the command **sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev**.

When I run R in the terminal this message shows up:

**/usr/bin/R: line 248: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory**

The same error is shown every time I try to install an r package. For every package I try to install the error "installation of package had non-zero exit status" shows up and the reason the package is not installed is the absence of the directory showed above.

Is there a solution to this problem?
Sorry for the poorness of my indications, if other information is needed I will update my question with screenshots or command lines.

Edit: as requested in the comments I post the output of the command **apt-cache policy r-base-core**

```
  r-base-core:
  Installed: 4.2.0-1.2004.0
  Candidate: 4.2.0-1.2004.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.1.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you installing R? what command are you running?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question. Did you get the error message during the installation? Both files `/usr/bin/R` and `/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths` are part of the package `r-base-core` which is required by `r-base`. Uninstalling the R packages and installing again might help. This question would better fit on https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question and sorry, if the topic doesn't fit this site I will remove the question. By the way I tried uninstalling and reinstalling r and nothing changes.

Comment: Did you add an repository to your Ubuntu setup (as described in [this Ubuntu README at CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)) ?  Can you show us the output of `apt-cache policy r-base-core` please?

Comment: Ok, you edited that.  `/usr/bin/R` is from `r-base-core` so that is good, and line 248 is a fairly simple `. "${R_HOME}/etc${R_ARCH}/ldpaths"` --- do you by chance have an older R installation in `/usr/local` that can get in the way?  Or is there anything else "special" about your machine?

Comment: I don't think I have any other old R installation or, at least, in the folder you wrote I don't have any R folder.

Comment: _Something_ on your system makes that line go funky.  Literally thousands of people run these same binaries, and they did get to you. Very weird. Please show (from shell) `R RHOME`.   It should be `/usr/lib/R`.  Next check the directory in question: what is in `/usr/lib/R/etc` -- there should be a file `ldpaths`.

Comment: Using the command `R RHOME` it shows `/usr/lib/R` indeed and into the `/usr/lib/R/etc` directory the file `ldpaths` is present.

Comment: The script `/usr/bin/R` which fails for you is run by `/bin/bash` so it is not due to having switched shells.  _Anything else_ unusual about your machine?

Comment: I don't think so, it's a Dell XPS-15 dual-booted with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04. Never had problems with other installations. (I use Conda for package management in python, don't know if it could be relevant.. sorry but I'm also quite inexperienced on these things)

Comment: Are you trying to start R from a Conda environment?  Try the plainest simplest terminal you can have.  Check what `env` returns.  It's not the fault of your Dell, it's not the fault of these binaries for Ubuntu you got from CRAN -- I run them too, and I have been the Debian maintainer behind them for 20 years.  But I cannot tell from here what else you to confuse the shell.  It _could be_ that you are sourcing something for Conda which messes this up,

Comment: No, I'm not into a Conda environment. Should I post the output of the `env` command?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste text to your question *as text* and format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. Please add all requested information to the question instead of using comments. Can you reproduce the problem by running `/usr/bin/R` (maybe with suitable arguments)? Try running it as `bash -x /usr/bin/R` and check if there is anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base r-base-dev r-base-core
sudo apt autoremove
```

I used the above lines to totally remove R, then reinstall `r-base r-base-dev r-base-core` this will automatically re-write the `/usr/lib/R/`. This should work without errors.